# Windows 8 MessageWebSocket http request garbage

Tags: windows-8, websocket, c++-cx

I'm developing a Windows 8 app that communicates with a node.js server using node.js/socket.io, and have ran into a pile of issues with connecting.  I decided to run a tcp sniffer application (microsoft network monitor 3.4), and noticed that before sending the http request, there is a bunch of garbage in my string:

`` C8 D7 19 87 09 1C C8 60 00 13 8C FA 08 00 45 00 00 C3 37 78 40 00 80 06 00 00 C0 A8 01 71 17 17 5C 67 C2 4F 01 BB 06 1A 36 71 A2 8B 48 C7 50 18 04 00 36 4D 00 00 47 45 54 20 2F 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D 0A 53 65 63 2D 57 65 62 53 6F 63 6B 65 74 2D 4B 65 79 3A 20 76 46 46 30 4F 4C 2F 55 63 53 49 6E 6F 70 46 67 52 69 6F 52 73 77 3D 3D 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 55 70 67 72 61 64 65 0D 0A 55 70 67 72 61 64 65 3A 20 57 65 62 73 6F 63 6B 65 74 0D 0A 53 65 63 2D 57 65 62 53 6F 63 6B 65 74 2D 56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3A 20 31 33 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20 32 33 2E 32 33 2E 39 32 2E 31 30 33 3A 34 34 33 0D 0A 0D 0A 
È×.‡..È`..Œú..E..Ã7x@.€...À¨.q..\gÂO.»..6q¢‹HÇP...6M..GET / HTTP/1.1..Sec-WebSocket-Key: vFF0OL/UcSInopFgRioRsw==..Connection: Upgrade..Upgrade: Websocket..Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13..Host: 192.168.1.1:443.... `` (the dots are \r\n in most cases)

Although I am using port 443, this is not a secured websocket - I am forced to use 443 because some smart phones only allow websockets to create socket connections on that port.

In C++, I am creating the websocket like so:

```
void Websocket::Connect(Platform::String ^host)
{
  if ( this->socket != nullptr ) return;
  try
  {
    Uri^ address = ref new Uri(host);
    readBuffer = ref new Buffer(1000);
    this->socket = ref new MessageWebSocket();
    this->socket->Control->MessageType = SocketMessageType::Utf8;
    this->socket->Control->MaxMessageSize = 512;
    this->socket->Closed += ref new TypedEventHandler<IWebSocket^, WebSocketClosedEventArgs^>( this, &Websocket::ServerClosed );
    this->socket->MessageReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<MessageWebSocket^, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs^>( this, &Websocket::MessageRecv );
    create_task(this->socket->ConnectAsync(address)).then([this](task<void> previousTask)
    {
      try
      {
        concurrency::task_status status = previousTask.wait();
        switch( status ) {
        case concurrency::task_status::completed:
          this->connected = true;
          break;
        default:
          socketErrorString = ref new Platform::String( L"Connection was cancelled" );
        }
      }
      catch(Exception^ exception)
      {
        this->connected = false;
        socketErrorString = ref new Platform::String( exception->Message->Data() );
        this->socket = nullptr;
      } catch( ... ) {
        this->connected = false;
        socketErrorString = ref new Platform::String( L"Unknown exception caught (inside connect)" );
        this->socket = nullptr;
      }
    });
  } catch( Exception ^exc ) {
    this->connected = false;
    socketErrorString = exc->Message; //ref new Platform::String( L"Unknown exception caught (outside connect)" );
    this->socket = nullptr;
  }
}
```

I can't see any sort of issue in the code, so I was hoping a few other sets of eyes may be able to.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of host you're using? Is it ws:// prefixed (not sure if that would help force MessageWebSocket to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, but worth a shot)?

Comment: I am specifying "ws://192.168.1.1:443/"

Comment: Actually, now that I take a closer look at what you pasted (and the fact you can read the request plaintext), it appears you pasted a complete ethernet frame.  The first 14 bytes are probably an ethernet header, followed by a IP header (starts at `45 00 00 C3`), followed by TCP header (starts at `C2 4F 01 BB`; note `01 BB` is your destination port of 443), followed by TCP payload (starts at `47 45 54 20`; the request data).  No TLS is being used.  Do you have access to the Node server's logs?  What is the request coming through?

Comment: That is to say: the request packet looks fine and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: If you toss your response in an answer I shall mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've pasted appears to be an [Ethernet frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame), but with 8 bytes stripped (7-byte preamble and 1-byte Start Frame Delimiter) because the network interface doesn't receive it.

The first fourteen bytes are the [Ethernet header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure): 6 bytes for the destination MAC address, 6 bytes for the source MAC address, and 2 bytes for the [EtherType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethertype), with `08 00` denoting that it is IPv4 packet.

The Ethernet payload follows the Ethernet header and, in this case, is an [IP datagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), so it starts with an [IP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) at offset 14 with byte `45` denoting an IPv4 header with a header length of 20 bytes.  At offset 23 you'll find the IP protocol of `06` denoting TCP.  At offset 26 you'll find the source IP address (`C0 A8 01 71`, i.e. 192.168.1.113).  At offset 30 you'll find the destination IP address.

The IP payload follows the IP header, and, in this case, it is a [TCP segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) starting with a [TCP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) at offset 34 with bytes `C2 4F` denoting a source port of 49743 and bytes `01 BB` denoting a destination port of 443.   At offset 46 you have `50` denoting a TCP header length of 20 bytes.

The TCP payload follows the TCP header, and, in this case, is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) starting at offset 54 with bytes `47 45 54 ...` being "GET...".

This request packet appears to be wellformed.  I believe your problem lies elsewhere.