# Socket.IO documentation for Windows 8 modern/metro app with MessageWebSocket

Tags: windows-8, c++11, websocket, socket.io, c++-cx

Relating to a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468894/windows-8-messagewebsocket-http-request-garbage), I am building a Windows 8 c++ App that requires me to connect to a Node.js server running socket.io.

Does socket.io use any sort of special protocol on top of websockets?  When I just do a dry connection, I get an error "HTTP Invalid Response."

I see a number of c++ websocket implementations, but I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to translate those concepts into the Windows 8 websocket implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this implementation for windows store apps, it's a port to WinRT (C#) of the .Net client of socket.io.

https://socketio4winrt.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have long since stopped working on this project, but your response looks like a good resource for other people to use.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed your question was posted about a year ago, this was mostly for future reference (my own as well, as I stumbled upon the same issue:)).