# Including socket.io-client-cpp and boost into a Windows 8 C++ App

Tags: c++, boost, windows-8, c++-cx

This question heavily relates to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486655/socket-io-documentation-for-windows-8-modern-metro-app-with-messagewebsocket) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468894/windows-8-messagewebsocket-http-request-garbage) questions.

I have built and included boost 1.51 into my project.

In my Socket.IO interface files (along with pch.h), this is the order of my includes:

```
#include <wrl.h>
#include <dwrite_1.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <agile.h>
#include "types.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "boost/cstdint.hpp"
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"
#include <sio_client_handler.hpp>
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
```

When I compile my code, I get the following output (only the first few lines):

> Error 1 error C2039: 'int_least8_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (SocketIO.cpp)  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdint
>
> Error 2 error C2873: 'int_least8_t' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (SocketIO.cpp) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdint
>
> Error 3 error C2039: 'int_least16_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' (SocketIO.cpp) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdint
>
> Error 4 error C2873: 'int_least16_t' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration (SocketIO.cpp)    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdint

There are over 100 of the above errors.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express C++, and haven't been able to come up with or find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own implementation of a socket.io client.  This was a work-related project, so I'll need to get permission to release it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C library headers with C++ library headers (wich is bad style), especially are you including `<cstdint>` right before `<stdint.h>`. 
IIRC, the `<cstdint>` of Visual C++ just includes `<stdint.h>` inside namespace std. That means, that you `#include` of `<stdint.h>` would not do anything (because of the include guards). Further more, `int_least8_t` etc. would reside *only* in namespacte std, and not in the global namespace.

I am not very sure if that is correct in VS 2012, but you can check that by diving into `<cstdint>`.

In any case, refer to those types inside the namespace std, as that is the standard compliant namespace they should be in. If you are using them often (as it seems), import them with using directives into whatever namespace you are working:

```
#include <cstdint>
//#include <stdint.h> <-- leave that one out, it's not C++ standard!

std::int_least8_t myIL8 = 5;

using std::int_least8_t;
int_least8_t anotherIL8 = 42;
```

Comment: This did not resolve the problem.  I added both as a test, as adding one or the other did not originally solve this issue, and left both for the time being.

Comment: so did you delve into `<cstdint>` (and maybe the headers included there) to look if `int_least8_t` is even defined somewhere in there? If it is, we'll need more code - the essential includes in your `.cpp` to maybe reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is indeed defined in cstdint.  I think the main problem is that boost and c++cx don't play nice together.

Comment: Are you sure about that? What brings you to the conclusion? Maybe you should create a minimal example, maybe a cpp with `void f() { std::int_least8_t; }` with at least included headers as possible, but retaining the error.